# How to insert an object (Model type object) into Collection Object in Laravel at specific index number?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-4, eloquent

I have read Dayle Rees's [Code Bright](https://daylerees.com/codebright/) to know more about Eloquent `Collection`s used in Laravel. Did some other research as well but couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

I want to insert an object (`Model` type object) into a `Collection` Object at a specific position.

For example:

This is the returned collection

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [0] => Attendance Object
        ([present_day] => 1)

    [1] => Attendance Object
        ([present_day] => 2)

    [2] => Attendance Object
        ([present_day] => 4) 

    [3] => Attendance Object
        ([present_day] => 5) 

)
```

As you can see above `[present_day]` have a values ranging from `1 to 5`, but the value, `3` is missing in the sequence. Now, what I really want to do is, I want to explicitly put a new `Attendance Object` at the Collection Object's position of `[2]` index number/position, thus by pushing the rest of the Attendance Object. I am really struggling to do this right. How can I do this to make above collection object to look like something as below:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [0] => Attendance Object
        ([present_day] => 1)

    [1] => Attendance Object
        ([present_day] => 2)

    [2] => Attendance Object    // This is where new object was added.
        ([present_day] => 3) 

    [4] => Attendance Object
        ([present_day] => 4) 

    [5] => Attendance Object
        ([present_day] => 5) 

)
```

I think there is some methods that will allow to do exactly like this if it was array. Since this is a `Collection`, I am not sure how to do it.

**Note:** I don't want to convert it this to array and do the insertion within array. For some reason, I want to have this output strictly in `Collection` object.

Comment: The collection object has an add method, use that and then re-sort the collection like so; `$collection->sortBy(function($model){ return $model->present_day; });` This will then reorder the collection to what you are wanting.

Comment: I havent tried the solution yet. Just by reading your comment, I am sure it should work. Actually, quite a nice way to get around with my problem.

Comment: Ill add as an answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To insert an item into a collection,refer to this answer; [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733020/how-can-i-add-an-item-into-a-laravel-eloquent-collection-by-index)

Basically, splits the collection, adds the item at the relevant index.

---

You can add the item to the `Eloquent\Collection` object with the `add` method;

```
$collection->add($item);  // Laravel 4
```

or

```
$collection->push($item); // Laravel 5
```

Then you can reorder the collection using the `sortBy` method;

```
$collection = $collection->sortBy(function($model){ return $model->present_day; });
```

This will reorder the collection by your `present_day` attribute.

---

Note that the above code will only work if you are using `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. If you are using a plain `Eloquent\Support\Collection`, there is no `add` method.

Instead, you can use an empty array offset, the same as inserting a new element in a normal array:

```
$collection[] = $item;
```

This form also works on the Eloquent version of `Collection`.

Comment: For everyone coming here and wondering that this doesn't work anymore [L5 and greater], try out `$collection->push($item);`. It appends an item at the collections end

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the accepted answer when there's no mention of the "index"

Comment: Just important to mention that we also got `$collection->prepend()` and `$collection->merge()`, sometimes they're useful as well, as it is just `collect()` to create a new `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

The put method sets the given key and value in the collection:

```
$collection = collect(['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk']);

$collection->put('price', 100);

$collection->all();

// ['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to enter a collection item at position 4

```
$position = 4;

$top = $collection->splice(0,$position);

$bottom = $collection->splice($position);

$top->push($newItem);

$collection = $top->concat($bottom);
```