# How can I add an item into a Laravel Eloquent Collection by index?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
$index = 2;
$collection->put($index, $item4);
```

For example if $collection looks like this:

```
$collection = [$item1, $item2, $item3];
```

I'd like to end up with:

```
$collection = [$item1, $item2, $item4, $item3];
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to splice it in, like this:

```
$collection->splice(2, 0, [$item4]);
```

Collections usually support the same functionality as regular PHP arrays. In this case, it's the [array_splice()](http://php.net/array_splice) function that's used behind the scenes.

By setting the second parameter to 0, you essentially tell PHP to "go to index 2 in the array, then remove 0 elements, then insert this element I just provided you with".

Comment: I'm getting an error. Non-static method Illuminate\Support\Collection::splice() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: Oops, my bad - should be ``->``, not ``::``. I'll update my example.

Comment: Tried that too. I'm getting. array_splice() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm really tired after new year's... I messed up the argument order. Please look again, _should_ work now. If that doesn't work put $item4 in an array.

Comment: No worries. Sorry, I'm getting. Trying to get property of non-object. When I try using push or prepend it works though, FYI. If that helps any.

Comment: Great! :) Glad to hear it.

Comment: `splice` modifies original collection and returns extracted elements, so it actually should be `$collection->splice(2, 0, [$item4]);`, when new item is an object it should be wrapped in array.

Comment: took me a great deal of time to realize splice() modifies the collection itself instead of returning a new one as avalue. Do you know of any way to "splice"  it and return the new collection?

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate a little on Joel's answer:

- `splice` modifies original collection and returns extracted elements
- new item is typecasted to array, if that is not what we want we should wrap it in array

Then to add `$item` at index `$index`:

```
$collection->splice($index, 0, [$item]);
```

or generally:

```
$elements = $collection->splice($index, $number, [$item1, $item2, ...]);
```

where `$number` is number of elements we want to extract (and remove) from original collection.

Comment: "new item is typecasted to array, if that is not what we want we should wrap it in array," I experienced object to array casting and was scratching my head, thanks for this note.