# Laravel foreach query builder result

Tags: laravel, foreach

I try to foreach a result then if name equal to "Apple "then i add a new row to next.

```
$list= Food::select('id', 'name')->get();

foreach ($list as $l) {
   if($l->name == 'Apple'){
       //Add 2 more item to next row
   } 
}
```

And my result output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Orange"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Blueberry"
    },
]
```

Here the result that i want to, for each to check if name is apple, then i need to add 2 more item manually.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple"
    },
    {
        "id": 1.1,
        "name": "Apple Pie"
    },
    {
        "id": 1.2,
        "name": "Apple Juice"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Orange"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Blueberry"
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you show us what you try ?

Comment: You can check this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397128/how-to-insert-an-object-model-type-object-into-collection-object-in-laravel-at

Comment: $l->push($item);

$item = {"id":1.1, "name": "Apple Pie"} ?

Comment: it's resolve your question ?

Comment: No, i want next 2 row, not add to last row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my own part, i use a temp array.

```
$list= Food::select('id', 'name')->get();

$tempList = array();

foreach ($list as $l) {
$tempList[] = $l;
   if($l->name == 'Apple'){
       $tempList[] = array('id' => 1.1, 'name' => 'Apple Pie');
   } 
}
```

But i think you can use Collection methods like "push"

[Collections Push](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-push)